# Automatically create class diagram from ActionScript code?

Tags: actionscript, uml, class-diagram

Is there a tool that can automatically generate class diagrams from Action Script code?

Comment: Sounds like a good side project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just searched google and quickly found, http://seantheflexguy.com/blog/2007/11/20/actionscript-30-uml-and-code-generation-tools/.

Perhaps more promising is: http://www.gskinner.com/gmodeler/  Goes from Diagram to stubs, it that is what you are looking for.

I know the UML tools space pretty well, but have not needed to use actionscript and UML.  Good Luck.

Answer (score 1):

You could try [UML4AS - UML for ActionScript and Flex](http://www.uml4as.com).